# D-finiteness of Hilbert series of non-commutative invariant ring under reductive group

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, invariant-theory, generating-functions

Let $G$ be reductive group over a field of characteristic $0$ ($GL_n$ fine for this question). Let $V$ be a linear representation of $G$. Then $G$ acts on the tensor algebra $T(V) = \bigoplus_{n \ge 0} V^{\otimes n}$ which is graded by $\deg(V) = 1$. Now form the Hilbert series of the ring of invariants:

$H(t) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \dim (V^{\otimes n})^G t^n$.

I believe I have a proof that this is a D-finite function, i.e., the derivatives of $H(t)$ with respect to $t$ form a finite-dimensional vector space over the field of rational functions. Is this result already stated in the literature?

Comment: Steven, I am puzzled - I thought I have outlined the following to you in Herstmonceux last summer: I think you can consider the highest weight words as walks, which yields a rational series.  The highest weight words of weight zero are then a diagonal of this series, and hence D-finite.  Is something wrong with this argument?

Comment: @MartinRubey : I completely forgot about this discussion actually. Anyway, it's a different proof that I have in mind but this result is just a consequence of something else being studied, so I wanted to know if I should cite something.

Comment: And also, I am a little confused by this argument: I don't want the dimension of the weight 0 piece. This is in general larger than the space of invariants. Could you be more specific about how I think of invariants as lattice paths?

Comment: By very basic representation theory, highest weight vectors of weight 0 coincide with the invariants.

Comment: @VictorProtsak: Yes. I can see why the weight 0 piece is given by walks in a lattice but I don't see how to isolate the highest weights using such a method.

Answer (score 1):

For the defining representation of $SL_n$ (if I'm not mistaken, for $GL_n$ there aren't any) the invariants are rectangular standard Young tableaux, so I think you could cite

*Zeilberger, Doron*, [**A holonomic systems approach to special functions identities**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0377-0427(90)90042-X), J. Comput. Appl. Math. 32, No.3, 321-368 (1990). [ZBL0738.33001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0738.33001).

The methods are in Section 3, the result (in terms of standard Young tableaux) is on page 22 of the preprint (http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/mamarim/mamarimPDF/holonomic.pdf).

Comment: I think that OP means that $V$ is *any* representation of $G$, not just the "defining" representation of $\rm {GL}_n$ (or $\rm {SL}_n$).

Comment: I have no time to check right now, but I think http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-115-01/S0002-9939-1992-1092920-8/S0002-9939-1992-1092920-8.pdf suffices.  Some complementary information is on page 3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4318.pdf